# Apache Redirect http -> https and non-www -> www, works all but 1 scenario

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have the code below to redirect all traffic to https on the subdomain www. I am using a load balancer as well through AWS to serve the SSL cert, so all traffic is on port 80. The rules below will redirect all traffic to https://www.example.com (the only place the certificate is valid) under all circumstances, except for when you enter the following url:

URL:

```
https://example.com
```

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP:HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

Comment: What happens now if you try to reach `https://example.com`?

Comment: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID - security error. All variations of the website redirect to `https://www.example.com`, except for `https://example.com`. 
`http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` both redirect to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: That is expected if the cert is only for `www.example.com` and you are trying to open `https://example.com`. If you are using AWS provided cert, just create a new one that will cover both domain names and attach that to your ELB listener.

Comment: I understand that. But what I'm saying is that I would like for the rewrite rules to ensure that users are always looking at `https://www.example.com`. Currently, `https://example.com` will not perform that redirect with the rules I have. I'm not sure why, but I'd like to fix that.

Comment: What happens if you, after browser security warning, choose to ignore warning and proceed to the website?

Comment: I've booted up another server and loaded the same configuration into it (for other reasons), and it works now.